# Can't get Protractor to "sleep"

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, jasmine, protractor

Can't get Protractor to sleep. 
In the spec file I have  `browser.driver.sleep(5000);`
I've tried all sort of things, but neither worked..

Thanks in advance

Comment: how about browser.sleep() instead of browser.driver.sleep() ??

Comment: browser.sleep() was one of the things I've tried and didn't work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Protractor sleeps only with a Promise

```
browser.sleep(1000).then(function(){
            console.log('sleep started');
            });

console.log('after sleep');
```

**Solution 2**

[Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/) async helpers:

- jasmine 1.3 - runs() / waitsFor()
- jasmine 2.* -  done()